# LayoutParams и параметры в XML

Tags: android, android-layout

В XML есть елемент,  и я хочу у него программно поменять отступ снизу, делаю это следующим образом:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

params.bottomMargin = (int) ScreenHelper.convertDpToPixel(8, mContext);

myView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

после чего вся верстка плывет, я правильно понимаю, что  после строки `myView.setLayoutParams(params);` все остальные параметры которые я указал в XML обнулятся? Или в чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = myView.getLayoutParams();

params.bottomMargin = (int) ScreenHelper.convertDpToPixel(8, mContext);

myView.setLayoutParams(params);
```